# Lighting is not the same in 2 different blend files

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I downloaded a tutorial blend file.
I wanted to have the same lightning in my own template file, but even I compared those two files they look different.

I disabled the "Sun" so you would only have the world emission light (EEVEE)

**Left** is "tutorial" file (I would like to have it like this) and **Right** is my "template" file.

[image]

**Edit**

This is the tutorial file:
[image]

This is my template file:
[image]

What settings (or another system setting??) might I possible look over?

Comment: please provide both blend file so we can compare it. Your screenshot doesn't help unfortunately. And please give the good names like "target" and "mytry" or so.

Comment: Unfortunately you cut off the top menu of the windows so I can't see the settings. At first glance it looks like the left is in _Rendered View_ mode while the right one is in _Material Preview_ mode. But that's just a guess.

Comment: @FGoqy To share your files use https://blend-exchange.com/ copy-paste given code and place it into your Q via edit

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Both screens are in rendered mode.

I do not use material preview at all. 

I will try to upload the 2 files

Comment: Your question was closed because it needed more details for clarification. As you can see in the comments, with the provided information we could all just have guessed and speculated. Btw, you don't have to edit the question to tell you will upload the files. Just edit in the uploaded files. Your question will be re-opened when it contains enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I was already asked to upload the files so it is not needed to close the question to begin with.  It is kind of disrespectful tbh. 
Just ask for more info and respect the person asking the question.

Comment: It is not meant disrespectful, as soon as a question is closed it is not accepting answers. This avoids getting speculative answers and showing up as answered when this might not be the case. Many other questions are closed at first and people simply provide more information to get it re-opened. Yes, you have been asked to upload a file, but since we do not know how long this will take (some need hours up to days to come back here and edit the question) it's better to close it meanwhile.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann  Got it :-) Thanks for clarification

Comment: Could be the World shader or Color Management

Answer (score 1):

**Your "Template" file**

[image]

**Your "Tutorial" file**

Go to *Render Properties > Indirect Lightning* and **Delete Lightning Cache** ...

[image]

... plus change under *Shader Editor > World > Background > Strength* to 0.500.

Now both looks the same with Sun enabled ...

[image]

To get the same lightning as the "tutorial" file you would have to find original **Environmental texture** that was used when *Indirect Lightning Cache* was *Baked*.

Visually it looks like blenders default "sunrise.exr" file delivered with app ... it has yellowish tint, but it is my guess ... lightning is not from the same direction act.

[image]
[image]

Note: And I don't think there is a chance to transfer just a Indirect Light Cache to another file ... that probably dent make a sense since this cache is based od current 3Dscene setup.